# From where can i get a detailed description of all the methods for the model in pytorch torchvison？

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am a beginner of pytorch ，when i read the source code of a project about mask rcnn .I don't konw from where can i  get  some information about some methods that i  don't understand .The official documentation doesn't seem very detailed?

```
# load an instance segmentation model pre-trained pre-trained on COCO
model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
# get number of input features for the classifier
in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
# replace the pre-trained head with a new one
model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)
```

Just like code above ,I could not get detailed information about the " roi_head" attribute from [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html#object-detection-instance-segmentation-and-person-keypoint-detection) of model .From where i can learn about it？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to find such thing on the documentation. You'll have to dive into the source code. Object Detection APIs, especially anchor-based two-stage approaches, are a little bit complex, and they tend to have too many components and hyper-parameters. PyTorch team already made an incredible job making this API modular and kinda easy-to-use. In the specific case of `roi_heads` you can take a look [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/detection/roi_heads.py) to learn more about it. In general, all components can be found in [`torchvision/models/detection`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/master/torchvision/models/detection).

Anyway, you can always open an issue, requesting them to expand the documentation. Or we can even do it ourselves and make a pull request :)

Answer (score 0):

From the docstring of `FasterRCNN`, `box_predictor` returns two things

> box_predictor (nn.Module): module that takes the output of box_head
> and returns the classification logits and box regression deltas.

So, `cls_score` is the classification logits.
Box regression deltas are stored in `bbox_pred`

Next, `cls_score` is nothing but a Dense layer with input and output shape defined by `in_channels` and `num_classes` (here `num_classes`= 2 according to the tut).

```
self.cls_score = nn.Linear(in_channels, num_classes)
```

`in_channels` is the input shape of `cls_score`. Because we want to replace the pre-trained head, we need to preserve information about `in_channels` in the new head.

```
# new head
FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)
```

P.S: In Tensorflow you can just freeze the learned layers and train the head only. These Pytorch lines of code achieve the same thing.